# How to encode after using HTML::Strip

Tags: html, perl, cp1252

I am trying to encode using cp1252 the HTML page since it has lot of special characters like `€` and `£` pounds but when I save those contents after using [`HTML::Strip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Strip). Contents were displayed as junk values. I tried to encode using cp1252 but its not working.

Please help me to fix the issue.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use HTML::Entities;
use HTML::Strip;

open( OUT, '>:encoding(cp1252)', "/home/local/ANT/jeyakuma/Desktop/test.html" );
my $URL = 'http://www.footlocker.eu/it/it/k/Customer-Service/Shipping.aspx';

my $agent    = LWP::UserAgent->new( agent => "Mozilla/5.0" );
my $request  = HTTP::Request->new( GET => $URL );
my $response = $agent->request($request);

# Check the outcome of the response
if ( $response->is_success ) {
    my $xp = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content( $response->decoded_content );
    my $raw_html = $xp->findnodes_as_string(
        '//div[@class="faq_text"]/p/strong/u[contains(.,\'spedizione Standard \')]'
    );

    my $hs         = HTML::Strip->new();
    my $clean_text = $hs->parse($raw_html);
    $hs->eof;
    print OUT $clean_text;

}
elsif ( $response->is_error ) {
    print "Error:$URL\n";
    print $response->error_as_HTML;
}
```

Expected output

```
£ 60/
```

Current output

```
Â£ 60/â‚
```

Comment: A quick looks at HTML::Strip reveals buggy handling of strings. `my $clean_text = decode_utf8($hs->parse(encode_utf8($raw_html)))` should do the trick. Functions provided by Encode. If someone wants to confirm and steal this to make an answer, go ahead. Gotta run.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but it throws an error "undefined subroutine &main::encode_utf8"

Comment: You have to grab them from Encode. `use Encode qw( decode_utf8 encode_utf8 );`